# Proguard and R8 don't optimize my library code

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-library, android-r8

When I connect my own library to project, it doesn't optimize. So:

1. In my lib, i turn on `minifyEnabled`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...
 debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
...
```

2. In project I implement my lib `implementation project(':somelib')`
3. In my project, i turn on `minifyEnabled`:

```
...
 debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
...
```

4. After build project, my lib is not optimized. I check it using APK Analyzer first then I use R8 and after it. 
   Also, I connect lib in over project, where it is not used at all. But after optimization count method increased because I implement unused lib.

Proguard contains a standard autogenerated proguard-android.txt file with rules for Parseble and for butterknife6. Proguard-rules.pro is empty.

```
// default proguard-android.txt file
...
-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public <init>(**, android.view.View); }

-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
*;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: can you post your proguard rules as well?

Comment: @Tirh It is a standard autogenerated proguard-android.txt file with rules for Parseble and for butterknife6. Proguard-rules.pro is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The `proguard-android.txt` file has a `-dontoptimize` rule that prevents optimizations. They actually mention in that file:

> Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
> include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
> instead you will need to point to the
> "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
> project.properties file.

So just replace

```
getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
```

with

```
getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
```